# Java code only working in IDE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build

I have written a little Java program which takes data from Excel sheets, does some stuff with it and put the data back to new Excel sheets.

It is working fine in the IDE (I am using IntelliJ) but when I build the Artifact nothing happens when I execute the built executable Jar File. Even with the following experiments I get the same result:

- Making a new project and copying the jar files into it then build the new project
- Making a new project and making new jar files, only copying the content of the old jars to the new ones. Then build the new project
- Using a different IDE (Eclipse) to build the project

So my conclusion was, that it is something with the code that stops the built executable jar from executing properly or that it is something with the Apache POI libraries.

So I made a new project with some easy sample code with the Apache POI libraries, build it and it worked. But my finished Excel project is still not working.

Here are my files:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9nMd9b1lJd9NEkyOVh0SG4zN28&usp=sharing

Comment: FYI, the google drive link shows "Judge Points Calculator -- Empty folder" and no files. Use github if you are familiar with it.
Without more information (whether you are using a build tool, how you are setting the classpath to POI libraries etc) it is not possible to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found it out myself.
I just forgot to sourround the loading of an image with try and catch and the Image wasn't been packed in the artifact so the final programm was not running.